# Do commutative $C^*$-algebras have torsion-free $K$-groups?

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory

Assume $X$ is a metrix space. In the case that $X$ is an inverse limit of one-dimensional finite CW complexes, it is known that $K_0(C(X))$ and $K_1(C(X))$ are torsion free . So I tried some examples where $X$ are two-dimensional finite CW complex, but faild to construct one that has non-torsion-free $K$-groups.

For instance, I considered the case that $X$ is constructed by attaching a 2-dimensional disc $D^2$ to $S^1$ via a degree 2 map. Then there is a short exact sequence

$$C_0(\mathbb R^2)\to C(X)\to C(S^1)$$
which gives a six-term exact sequence of $K$-groups

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb Z @>>> K_0(C(X)) @>>> \mathbb Z\\
@AAA @. @VVV \\
\mathbb Z @<<< K_1(C(X)) @<<< 0
\end{CD}$$

Since the boundary map on the left side is an isomorphism ($K_1(S^1)\simeq K_1(C_0(\mathbb R))\simeq K_0(C_0(\mathbb R^2))$), $K_*(C(X))$ is torsion-free.

I also tried to attach more components to $X$, but none could change the fact that the boundary maps are too simple.

Is there an example that $C(X)$ has non-torsion-free $K$-groups? I really can not imagine when this could happen.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169270/topological-k-theory-for-commutative-c-algebras, Rasmus' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No definitely not.

Every abelian group appears as the $K_0$-group or the $K_1$-group of a commutative $C^*$-algebra. This is proven in Blackadar's K-theory book.